# OneToMany Mapping POJO to JSON Spring

Tags: java, json, postgresql, spring-boot, mapping

I use PostgreSQL and I have these tables, address and company with relation OneToMany on address to company. I want to retrieve a list of addresses which each of them contains a list of companies. I implemented the join between these two tables and I retrieved the data below:

When execute this query:

```
select ad.id,ad.geolocation, ca.id, ca.name_en, ca.name_el from 
address as ad right join company_address as ca on (ad.id = ca.address_id);
```

I retrieved this table and I want to map it in JSON format as below:

```
1;"0101000020E6100000C006335CD3043840504BBDB89EC14140";  6; "Petros"; 
1;"0101000020E6100000C006335CD3043840504BBDB89EC14140"; 12; "Shop3";
1;"0101000020E6100000C006335CD3043840504BBDB89EC14140"; 13; "Shop3";
7;"0101000020E6100000A03418D984063840D8DD978E94C14140";  7; "Mike";
7;"0101000020E6100000A03418D984063840D8DD978E94C14140"; 14; "Shop5";
7;"0101000020E6100000A03418D984063840D8DD978E94C14140"; 15; "Shiop8";
9;"0101000020E6100000804127840E163840CC28965B5AC64140"; 10; "Shop2";
9;"0101000020E6100000804127840E163840CC28965B5AC64140"; 11; "Shop3";
```

Do you know how can convert the results in the format below using an elegant way?

POJO:

```
private Long id;
private Geolocation geolocation;
private List<ShopObj> shops;
```

ShopObj Class:

```
class ShopObj{
  private Long id;
  private String nameEn;
}
```

Json Data:

```
{
  "code": "200",
    "data": [
       {
        "id": 1,
        "geolocation": "0101000020E6100000C006335CD3043840504BBDB89EC14140",
        "shops": [
          {
           "id": 6,
            "nameEn": "Petros"
          },
          {
            "id": 12,
            "nameEn": "Shop3"
          },
          {
            "id": 13,
            "nameEn": "Shop3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "geolocation": "0101000020E6100000A03418D984063840D8DD978E94C14140",
        "shops": [
          {
            "id": 7,
            "nameEn": "Mike"
          },
          {
            "id": 14,
            "nameEn": "Shop5"
          },
          {
            "id": 15,
            "nameEn": "Shiop8"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "geolocation": "0101000020E6100000804127840E163840CC28965B5AC64140",
        "shops": [
          {
            "id": 10,
            "nameEn": "Shop2"
          },
          {
            "id": 11,
            "nameEn": "Shop3"
          }
        ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the code below and worked for my case, but do you know if is there and auto way to map my data?

```
 List<ProductTest> productTests = productRepository.getProductTest();
    Map<Long, ProductT> products = new HashMap<Long, ProductT>();
    for (ProductTest pt : productTests) {
        ProductT productT = products.get(pt.getId());
        if (productT == null) {
            productT = new ProductT(pt.getId(), pt.getNameEl(), new ArrayList<MediaT>());
            products.put(pt.getId(), productT);
        }
        MediaT mediaT = new MediaT(pt.getMediaId(), pt.getMultimediaPath());
        productT.getMediaList().add(mediaT);
    }
    return products.values();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

1. Create an empty `Map<Long, POJO>`, containing the POJOs as values, and their ID as keys
2. Iterate throug your rows.
3. For each row, get the POJO ID, and get the corresponding POJO from the map. If it's not in the map yet, create the POJO and add it to the map
4. create a Shop for the current row, and add the shop to the list of shops of the POJOs obtained/created at the previous step
5. At the end, the values() of the map is the `Collection<POJO>` that you want to serialize to JSON.